# Specifying version numbers in Bower

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, semantic-versioning

When writing bower.json you can specify version numbers in your dependencies.
Sometimes I see people writing

```
{
...
    "devDependencies" : {
        "grunt" : "~0.3.13",
    }
}
```

What exactly does the ~ mean? Why not write >=0.3.13?

Is this some sort of best practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the bower (and npm) version syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030170/what-is-the-bower-and-npm-version-syntax)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's [semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver/) and the notation is the same as `>=0.3.13 <0.4.0`, which will match all `patch` releases after and including `0.3.13`, but not `0.4.0`. This means you'll get bug fixes (`patch`), but not new features (`minor`). `>=0.3.13` is not recommended as it will match anything above which will at some point break.