# bower packages update crashed the app - how to roll back

Tags: angularjs, git, gruntjs, bower

I've installed another additional module for my app with `bower`. As project dependencies in `bower.json` were not very strict, and a lot of time passed since last update, bower updated a lot of  packages to newer ones. There were a lot of changes, and incompatibility between packages was the reason for major app crash.

I never asked for this, not a good moment for total upgrade&debug. How can I just roll back to previous packages?

- Original package sources are in `.gitignore` and built with `grunt` into one file (so I can't just revert the commit - as packages renewed by bower will be the same in the next build)
- I couldn't find out the old package set which was OK for my app (as package sources with specific version numbers are in `.gitignore`) ***UPD***: found versions in built file, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958758/1601185)
- I couldn't find any information about sort of "bower package history" or "bower undo".

**UPD**: I solved the issue for myself and described the solution in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958758/1601185). But I'm really not sure it's a good way, and would be grateful for any kind of mentorship about the subject.

Comment: I'd recommend to try and fix the issues that is causing your app to crash.

Comment: @WayneEllery, your point of view is right, and we should do clean and ideal apps. But sometimes you don't have time to debug tons of legacy code - and you just want to return to previous state, planing an _important_ issue for future as a less _urgent_.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Bower. Have you tried this to install the older version of Angular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030170/what-is-the-bower-version-syntax

Comment: @WayneEllery , thanks for your comments. I reworked the question to make it more clear & specific, could you please upvote it, or point out what else should I do to make it a good question? I am new to stackoverflow, hope I'll learn to post better questions soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem for myself by digging into incompatiblities showed by `bower`, and finding compromise package set. Main issues were between newest `angular` asked by some packages and `angular-ui-bootsrap` working with older versions only for that moment. Also there were some issues with other newest packages, which I downgraded and will solve later on. So I used `bower install [PackageName]#=[SpecificPackageVersion]` (can use `--save` here to save it to bower.json) for manually setting compromise packages.

At the moment I realized, that there were old **package versions in license comment blocks** in the previous commits of built file, so in order to have old working set of packages I could:

1. `git checkout HEAD~1` to have old file, which was built with previous package set
2. `grep` (search) package names or license comments in it
3. `bower install [PackageName]#=[OldWorkingPackageVersion]` (can use `--save` to save it to bower.json)
4. `git checkout [BranchName]` to make HEAD back
5. Make build (with previous packages installed again)

However,  I'm not sure it's a good solution, and would be grateful for any kind of clarification about the subject.