# prevent bower from updating angular version

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm trying to install [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) in my project using bower but the `bower install git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git` keeps updating my version of angular from 1.3.15 to angular 1.4.

Here is my bower.json

```
    "name": "eeee",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": ">=1.3.*",
        "json3": "~3.3.1",
        "es5-shim": "~3.0.1",
        "jquery": "~2.1.4",
        "angular-resource": ">=1.3.*",
        "angular-cookies": ">=1.3.*",
        "angular-sanitize": ">=1.3.*",
        "angular-route": ">=1.3.*"
}
```

If I run:

```
`bower install git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git`
```

The result is:

```
bower angular-filter#*      not-cached git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git#*
bower angular-filter#*         resolve git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git#*
bower angular#>=1.3.*           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.0
bower angular#>=1.3.*         validate 1.4.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.3.*
bower angular#1.4.0             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.0
bower angular#1.4.0           validate 1.4.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.0
bower angular-filter#*        download https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/archive/v0.5.4.tar.gz
bower angular-filter#*         extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-filter#*        resolved git://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git#0.5.4
bower angular#>=1.3.*          install angular#1.4.0
bower angular-filter#~0.5.4    install angular-filter#0.5.4

angular#1.4.0 client/bower_components/angular

angular-filter#0.5.4 client/bower_components/angular-filter
└── angular#1.4.0
```

which means my angular updated to 1.4 when I want 1.3.15. How can I prevent bower from automatically updating my angular version when installing angular-filter?

Comment: Why not explicitly asking for "angular : 1.3.15"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a specific version, then you should remove the `">="` before `"1.3.*"`. This basically means: "Version 1.3.x or anything more recent."

For a fixed version, just use: `"angular": "1.3.5",`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412378/606920), Bower is using the Semver syntax. So you can find other ways to specifiy versions on this page: https://github.com/npm/node-semver