# What is the difference between ~ and ^ in bower.json?

Tags: javascript, bower

I have this bower.json file.

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-loader": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.0",
    "html5-boilerplate": "~5.2.0",
    "angular-google-chart": "^0.1.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.0.6"
  }
}
```

For some dependencies, I see ^ as in `"angular-material": "^1.0.6"`. For others, I see ~ as in `"html5-boilerplate": "~5.2.0"`. What is the difference between ^ and ~?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030170/what-is-the-bower-version-syntax

Comment: Your can found your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31845544/5368495

Comment: [Node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1)

Comment: One question. Does Bower and npm share the same semver?

Comment: All the package managers share the same conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) and it actually comes from [npm's package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

- ~version is "Approximately equivalent to version"
- ^version is "Compatible with version"