# angular (1.5.8-build.4928+sha.e8c2e11) - wrong version

Tags: angularjs, installation, bower-install

I am trying to install angular 1.4.5 using bower.json. This is how my bower.json file looks like

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.5",
    "angular-resource": "1.4.5",
    "angular-route": "1.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5"
  }
}
```

after saving, this file got changed to

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.5",
    "angular-resource": "1.4.5",
    "angular-route": "1.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8-build.4928+sha.e8c2e11"
  }
}
```

and i guess because of this, angular is not installing, it says wrong version.
check under Bower folder 
[image]

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use `~` sign in `"angular": "~1.4.x"`

```
 {
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.x",
    "angular-resource": "1.4.5",
    "angular-route": "1.4.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5"
  }
}
```

for more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030170/what-is-the-bower-version-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues

It will be better use this also. Add new issue and you will definitely find something. I never got this kind of problem anytime when I was installing or doing anything with AngularJS.

Thanks

Comment: this is not an answer :P but i up-voted you :D  . thanks for taking time respond.

Answer (score 1):

Add below resolution and delete `Bower` folder.

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.5"
}
```

This will install v1.4.5 of angular

I hope this helps you

Cheers!