# how do you get the latest version of Polymer elements using bower?

Tags: asp.net, polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I am experimenting with an asp.net core MVC web app using Polymer, and largely things seem to be going well. I used the now built in bower.json file to specify required packages (eg paper-fab), and they were dutifully installed. Nearly every time I could just use the package name and version from the appropriate Polymer catalogue page ([example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-ripple)). But with a couple of the pages (paper-ripple and paper-card) bower can't find the specified version, so I tried the wildcard approach which resolved to a much earlier version. For paper-ripple it didn't seem to cause any problems, but paper-card just doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my bower.json file:

`{
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "jquery": "2.2.0",
      "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
      "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
      "polymer": "1.4.0",
      "PolymerElements/paper-material": "1.0.6",
      "PolymerElements/iron-icons": "1.1.3",
      "PolymerElements/iron-image": "1.2.5",
      "PolymerElements/paper-button": "1.0.13",
      "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button": "1.1.3",
      "PolymerElements/app-layout": "0.10.4",
      "PolymerElements/paper-header-panel": "1.1.6",
      "PolymerElements/paper-toolbar": "1.1.7",
      "PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel": "1.0.10",
      "PolymerElements/paper-fab": "1.2.1",
      "PolymerElements/paper-item": "1.2.1",
      "PolymerElements/paper-listbox": "1.1.2",
      "PolymerElements/paper-ripple": "*",
      "PolymerElements/paper-card": "*",
      "normalize-css": "4.1.1"
    },
    "resolutions": {
      "polymer": "^1.2.1",
      "paper-ripple": "^1.0.0",
      "font-roboto": "^1.0.1"
    }
  }`

I know I could just download the latest versions from the catalogue, but I'd rather continue using bower if I can.

Of course it's always possible I am doing the cards wrong!

```
<link rel="import" href="~/lib/bower/paper-card/paper-card.html" />

<paper-material main elevation="0">

    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <paper-card heading="Card @i">
            <div class="card-content">Some content @i</div>                    
        </paper-card>
    }

</paper-material>
```

The cards are just being output into the DOM like this (usually when using chrome dev tools I can see all the local DOM inside Polymer elements, but not in this case):

```
<paper-card heading="Card 0">
    <div class="card-content">Some content 0</div>                    
</paper-card>
```

**EDIT: Potential Workaround**

So I have found that rather than directly editing the bower.json file in Visual Studio (which updates all your packages when saving), if I open up cmd in the same directory as the bower.json file and run bower commands from there I can install the versions shown in the Polymer catalog. For example `bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-ripple` which then updates the bower.json file accordingly. Perhaps this is the best way of doing it rather than relying editing it manually and relying on VS to update the packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install latest version on every `bower install` command you can add `caret(^)` to all your bower dependencies. Currently you have hard coded all the versions that needs to be used.
You can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030170/what-is-the-bower-version-syntax) for more details on bower versions

Comment: excellent, that's very helpful thanks. unfortunately the latest versions on bower for the 2 packages i mentioned are not the latest. For example if i run `bower info paper-card` from cmd it shows 0.1.5 as the latest version, but the polymer [catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card) shows 1.1.3 as the current version whilst also telling you to install using bower (similar situation for paper-ripple)

Comment: actually, I just tried using the `caret(^)` for all packages, and while it worked for some, it did not work for all of them, including one of the problem ones (paper-ripple). I get: "ENORESTARGET Tag/branch ^ does not exist"

Comment: Can you post how you used it for `paper-ripple`

Comment: It would have been `"PolymerElements/paper-ripple": "^",` as it happens I think I found a work around which I will add to my question shortly

Comment: That is the issue, you need to add version number after `caret` it'll be "^1.0.0"