# What are the prefix symbols "^", "~" and those without in the package version in package.json files?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Example:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60"
```

`"@angular/cli"` has no symbol

`"@angular/compiler-cli"` has `^` symbol

`"@types/node"` has `~` symbol

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030170/what-is-the-bower-and-npm-version-syntax/20412378#20412378

Comment: [Semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver)