# Semantics of bower when specifying package versions

Tags: bower

Can anyone explain the semantics of bower when specifying the package version?

I understand these:

```
"requirejs": "2.1.10",
"requirejs": ">=2.1"
```

But what about something like `"requirejs": "~2.1"`?

Also, does `"requirejs": "*"` mean the latest version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying version numbers in Bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019944/specifying-version-numbers-in-bower)

Comment: what about *, does it means that latest version?

Comment: `*` means "any version allowed". This versioning scheme is called `semver`. See my link above for the detailed guide.